# Elliptic Operators on Vector Bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-operators

I know the kernel of an elliptic operator on a compact manifold has finite dimension. Is the kernel of an elliptic operator on sections of a vector bundle a finite dimensional space?

Comment: yes. see chap. 10 of these notes. http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: But assuming the vector bundle is over a compact manifold.

Comment: I think that this result is due to Bochner, Tensor fields with finite bases, Ann. Math. 1951 (53) p. 400-411. But Nicolaescu's book is where I would look for a proof.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no. As an example, the spin Dirac operator on even-dimensional complex hyperbolic space has nontrivial $L^2$-sections in its kernel. Because the space is symmetric, in particular homogeneous, one can conclude that the $L^2$-kernel must be infinite-dimensional. The proof uses some results of Harish-Chandra on representations of semi-simple noncompact Lie groups. For more details, see [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1013035721335) or [arXiv:math/9905089](http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/math/9905089).

Comment: For a more elementary example of infinite dimensional kernel on noncompact manifolds, you could just look at the kernel of the Cauchy Riemann operator on complex functions of one complex variable.

Comment: @BenMcKay You are right. I was somehow automatically thinking of $L^2$ sections, even though this was not demanded.